# Python - percorrer uma lista - substituir palavra dentro do word (.docx)

Tags: python

Bom dia!
Preciso de um auxílio...

Tenho um arquivo word, com nome de '**teste.docx**'.

Gostaria de substituir cada termo dentro dele por strings que estão numa lista. Veja exemplo.

O problema que está ocorrendo é que a alteração não está entrando em loop.

Podem me ajudar? Obrigado desde já!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

----x----

```
from docx import Document

caminho = 'D:\\Users\\89614879\\Desktop\\Nova pasta\\'
arquivo = 'teste.docx'
docword = caminho + arquivo

doc = Document(docword)

lista = [['111','adm','Pedro Paulo'],['222','cont','Luiz Carlos'],['333','econ','Jorge Fernando'],['444','jorn','Claudia Leite']]
qtd_linhas = len(lista)
qtd_colunas = len(lista[0])

nome_arq = ['Pedro Paulo', 'Luiz Carlos', 'Jorge Fernando','Claudia Leite']

for i, paragrafo in enumerate(doc.paragraphs):
    palavra = '<' + str(i) + '>'
    if palavra in paragrafo.text:
        for x in range(qtd_linhas):
            for y in range(qtd_colunas):
                paragrafo.text = paragrafo.text.replace(palavra, str(lista[x][y]))
                new_docword = caminho + nome_arq[y] + '.docx'
                doc.save(new_docword)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código está quase bom, só algumas coisas que estão invertidas.

A lógica é a seguinte, primeiro, faça o `for` na lista, pois cada elemento da lista significa um novo arquivo que você vai gerar. Em cada iteração, aplique as substituições no arquivo inteiro e salve o arquivo, antes de começar novamente com novo arquivo e novas substituições:

```
import os
from docx import Document

caminho = r'D:\Users\89614879\Desktop\Nova pasta'
arquivo = 'teste.docx'
docword = os.path.join(caminho, arquivo)

lista = [['111','adm','Pedro Paulo'],['222','cont','Luiz Carlos'],['333','econ','Jorge Fernando'],['444','jorn','Claudia Leite']]
nome_arq = ['Pedro Paulo', 'Luiz Carlos', 'Jorge Fernando','Claudia Leite']

for novo_nome, substituicoes in zip(nome_arq, lista):
    doc = Document(docword)
    for paragrafo in doc.paragraphs:
        for i, substituicao in enumerate(substituicoes):
            palavra = '<' + str(i) + '>'
            if palavra in paragrafo.text:
                paragrafo.text = paragrafo.text.replace(palavra, substituicao)
    new_docword = os.path.join(caminho, novo_nome + '.docx')
    doc.save(new_docword)
```

Comment: nosklo, agradeço sua atenção. Obrigado pela orientação.